# How can I construct a moose object from a hash generated from one of the attributes?

Tags: perl, moose

I have a couple of packages:

```
package FOO;
use Moose;
has 'obj' => (is=>'ro');
sub hash { 
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->make_hash($self->obj}; 
}
```

and another package extending FOO:

```
package FOOBAR;
use Moose;
extends 'FOO';
has [qw/val1 val2/] => (is => 'rw');
sub BUILD {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->val1($self->hash->{val1});
    $self->val2($self->hash->{val2});
}
```

Basically I want to do `FOOBAR->new(obj=>$obj);` and use a hash generated from `$obj` to populate the attributes specified in `FOOBAR` (~20 or so attributes)

Is using 'BUILD' like this a good way of solving it?

Answer (score 1):

Why? Then you end up with two copy of the data. Delegate instead.

```
has obj => (
   is      => 'ro',
   handles => {
      val1 => sub { my $self = shift; my $obj = $self->obj; ... },
      val2 => sub { my $self = shift; my $obj = $self->obj; ... },
   },
);
```

If the accessors are practically identical, you can do something like

```
sub make_obj_accessor {
   my ($name) = @_;
   return sub {
      my $self = shift;
      my $obj = $self->obj;
      ... $name ...
   };
}

has obj => (
   is      => 'ro',
   handles => {
      (map make_obj_accessor($_), qw(
         val1
         val2
      ))
   },
);
```

Of course, if you really only have a hash, all you need is

```
FOOBAR->new( %hash )
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm working with a hash ($self->hash, which does some magic to construxt a has from $self->obj), and afaik i can't delegate to keys in a hash?

Comment: @simon_, You say it's a hash, but then you continue to call it `$obj` and say the hash is actually constructed from it. Which one is it? If `$obj` is an object, use delegates. Place any "magic" you need in the delegate. (e.g. `val1 => sub { my $self = shift; my $obj = $self->obj; ... }`)

Comment: Well, the $obj I pass to the constructor is an object. The hash with the values I want to use for the FOOBAR attributes is generated from $obj with a custom method 'make_hash'. I don't really se how this was unclear..

Comment: thanks for the updated code. i guess i can do something like this!

Comment: actually... The suggested delegate approach is going to be inefficient because i would have to mangle/decode/etc $self->obj in ever sub ref in 'handles'